# Open3d Mesh : metrics of the inputs for mesh box?

Tags: mesh, open3d

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhAkq.png)

What are the metrics for the width, height, and depths when you create from the Open3d geometry?
Are they in cm, meters, inches?

I have read the document, but it is not mentioned anywhere.

It is a simple question, but please help me!

Comment: Please check the image description above to clarify my question!

Answer (score 0):

In Open3D, there is no concept of units. You need to make sure that all your geometries use same unit, whether its CM or meter.

BTW, I prefer to keep everything in standard metric, meter, since often you have to export data from Open3D to files which needs to be read by external software. These software might assume data to be in standard metric system.

Comment: For e.g. - By default Blender measures using the metric system